# cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle, instantclient

I am getting

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred error while connecting oracle from python.
```

I have installed python 3.7.0 and instantclient_11_2.

Below are the process i am doing,

```
import cx_Oracle
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn( '<ip>', 1521, service_name = '<given service name>')

connection = cx_Oracle.connect('user', 'pwd', dsn_tns)
```

I have set system veriable `PATH` where `oci.dll` is present.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
connection = cx_Oracle.connect('user', 'pwd', cx_Oracle.makedsn( '<ip>', '1521',None,'<given service name>'))
```

Looks the same but works different in my ubuntu server.

Also make sure to put the port between ' '

Answer (score 0):

You should also be able to use the following connect string if the database resides on the same machine:

```
connection = cx_Oracle.connect('user/pwd@localhost/service_name')
```

Note that a service_name value is required. You can't use the empty string!