# how to fix cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred

Tags: python, oracle, sqlplus, cx-oracle, oracleclient

I am trying to run a Python script to insert some data into an Oracle table, from a docker image.

I was given following connection string :

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_TIMEOUT=3)(RETRY_COUNT=2)(FAILOVER=ON)(LOAD_BALANCE=NO) (ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host_1)(PORT=1521))) (ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host_2)(PORT=1521))) (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=service_name)))
```

I'm trying to connect using `cx_Oracle` package :

```
try:
    # establish a new connection
    with cx_Oracle.connect(self.oracle_user,
                            self.oracle_pwd,
                            self.oracle_dsn) as connection:
        logger.info('ElasticsearchFinder.oracle_write : connexion established with DB')
```

with `oracle_dsn` being the connexion string (minus the `jdbc:oracle:thin:@` part)

I also tried things like

```
cx_Oracle.connect(self.oracle_user+'/'+self.oracle_pwd+'@'+self.oracle_dsn)
```

as seen in some examples, but I always get the following timeout error :

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred
```

`telnet host 1521` works fine, I also tried changing the `CONNECT_TIMEOUT` value.

I also tried

```
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(self.oracle_host, self.oracle_port, service_name = self.oracle_service_name)
cx_Oracle.connect(self.oracle_user,self.oracle_pwd,dsn_tns)
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51836874/cx-oracle-databaseerror-ora-12170-tnsconnect-timeout-occurred) but then I get

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
```

I am running my script from a Docker image build with Dockerfile :

```
FROM oraclelinux:7.8
RUN  yum -y install oracle-release-el7 && \
     yum-config-manager --enable ol7_oracle_instantclient && \
     yum -y install oracle-instantclient18.3-basic && \
     rm -rf /var/cache/yum
COPY ./fetch_session_iptv.py /opt/
COPY ./conf/fetch_session_iptv.conf /opt/conf/
#COPY ./conf/certs/* /opt/conf/certs/
COPY ./logs /opt/logs
RUN yum install -y \
    #https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/developer/x86_64/getPackage/oracle-instantclient18.3-basic-18.3.0.0.0-2.x86_64.rpm \
    https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/developer/x86_64/getPackage/python-cx_Oracle-7.3-1.el7.x86_64.rpm \
    https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/developer/x86_64/getPackage/python36-pytz-2016.10-2.0.1.el7.noarch.rpm
COPY ./python_requirements/elasticsearch-7.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl .
COPY ./python_requirements/certifi-2020.4.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl .
COPY ./python_requirements/urllib3-1.25.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl .
RUN pip3 install --user \
    certifi-2020.4.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl \
    urllib3-1.25.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl \
    elasticsearch-7.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl \
    cx_Oracle
RUN sh -c "echo /usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64/lib > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf"
RUN ldconfig
RUN export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64/
RUN yum -y install telnet
#CMD ["/bin/bash"]
CMD [ "python3", "/opt/fetch_session_iptv.py" ]
```

I can't understand what's going wrong?

[**UPDATE**] I've set

- `ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64/bin`
- `TNS_ADMIN=$ORACLE_HOME/admin`
- `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64/lib`
- `PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME`

I've added a `tnsnames.ora` file in TNS_ADMIN directory, with

```
CNX=(DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_TIMEOUT=3)(RETRY_COUNT=2)(FAILOVER=ON)(LOAD_BALANCE=NO) (ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host_1)(PORT=1521))) (ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host_2)(PORT=1521))) (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=service_name)))
```

Now, when I try `sqlplus MY_USER@CNX` I get the same :

```
ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occured
```

but at least it seems to accept the connexion string and user. Prior to setting all the environment variables correctly, I only got different TNS error messages about `TNS: listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor` or the net service name being incorrect.

[**UPDATE 2**]
I've checked with the person who gave me all connexion info: user, password and connection string are correct. They're running Oracle Database 12c (12.1.0.2.0), which according to [this page](https://oraclefact.wordpress.com/2018/04/05/client-server-interoperability-support-matrix-for-different-oracle-versions-doc-id-207303-1/) is compatible with the 18c client I'm using.

I don't know what else could be a possible reason for this timeout error?

Comment: Have you defined an environment variable called `TNS_ADMIN`, and set pointing to the directory of `TNSNAMES.ORA` file ?

Comment: I am not using `TNSNAMES.ORA` file to get connection info, is Oracle only checking that file by default?

Comment: Also, when I try to set any environment variable into my Dockerfile (`RUN export my_env_variable = /usr/....`), then `docker exec echo $my_env_variable`, it always returns an empty string, I don't get why it doesn't seem to work

Comment: For a start, never set ORACLE_HOME with Instant Client.  It leads to issues such as hitting ORA-1804.  Instant Client is not an Oracle Home-based install.  Secondly, the default directory for network files is /usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64/lib/network/admin.  Put the files there and unset TNS_ADMIN.

Answer (score 1):

Start by using the equivalent connection string in cx_Oracle:

```
self.oracle_dsn = "(DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_TIMEOUT=3)(RETRY_COUNT=2)(FAILOVER=ON)(LOAD_BALANCE=NO) (ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host_1)(PORT=1521))) (ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host_2)(PORT=1521))) (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=service_name)))"

try:
    # establish a new connection
    with cx_Oracle.connect(self.oracle_user,
                            self.oracle_pwd,
                            self.oracle_dsn) as connection:
        logger.info('ElasticsearchFinder.oracle_write : connexion established with DB')
```

The cx_Oracle manual on connecting and connect strings is [here](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html).

Personally I'd use 19c Instant Client, which will connect to the same DB versions as 18c - and doesn't need to have `ldconfig` run.  See [Docker for Oracle Database Applications in Node.js and Python](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python-part-1).

Update your question with information and I can update this answer likewise.

Comment: That's already the connection string I'm using, I'll try with 19c Instant Client